# Adding a partition (device) back to the launcher

Tags: launcher, devices, dconf, gsettings

I am new to Ubuntu and I unknowingly removed the shortcut to the drives and partitions from the launcher as it was totally cluttered initially. But now I'm having trouble accessing files and folders by going to each and every drive.

Is it possible to add the partitions to the "Launcher" as prior to removal of the icons?

Comment: Hi Sunil, did you manage?

Comment: Yeah! It actually works like a charm! :D Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the devices (accidentally) from the launcher, you "blacklisted" them, meaning the ones you removed are no longer visible in the Unity Launcher. To undo, and make them show up again, run the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "[]"
```

(open a terminal window by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and paste the command above in the terminal window, press <kbd>RETURN</kbd>)

This will make any device you might have removed from the launcher visible again.